# Vector bundle construction lemma

Tags: differential-geometry

> John M lee, Introduction to smooth manifolds, Exercise 5-4:
>
> Let $M$ be
>   a smooth manifold and let $\{U_α\}_{α∈A}$ be an open cover of $M$. Suppose for
>   each $α, β ∈ A$ we are given a smooth map $τ_{αβ} : U_α∩U_β → GL(k,\mathbb{R})$ such
>   that $τ_{αβ}(p)τ_{βγ}(p) = τ_{αγ}(p)$, $p∈ U_α ∩ U_β ∩ U_γ$ is satisfied for all $α, β, γ ∈ A$. Show that there is a
>   smooth rank $k$ vector bundle $E → M$ with smooth local trivializations $Φ_α
>  : π^{−1}(U_α) → U_α×\mathbb{R}^k$ whose transition functions are the given maps $τ_{αβ}$.
>   [Hint: Define an appropriate equivalence relation on $\coprod_{α∈A}(U_α × \mathbb{R}^k)$,
>   and use the bundle construction lemma.]

But the [bundle construction lemma](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=Vector%20Bundle%20Construction%20Lemma&source=bl&ots=xY7-Gbw6D0&sig=2bmWbqis2fVRfFmAQ6LnM8NwlvY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h966UKHtAcyviQfwrYCoAg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Vector%20Bundle%20Construction%20Lemma&f=false) has a different hypothesis. It uses $E= \coprod _{p \in M} E_p$ where $E_p$ is a real vector space. How can I use the lemma?

Comment: The obvious equivalence relation should turn the union of trivializations into a union of vector spaces indexed by $M$ (transition isomorphisms will make sure of the vector space structure) so that you can use the bundle construction lemma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X=\coprod_{\alpha\in A}(U_\alpha\times\mathbf R^k)$. You want to find a relation ${\sim}$ on $X$ such that $X/{\sim}$ and $E$ are in bijection. The obvious candidate for a bijection is the one defined on each $U_\alpha\times\mathbf R^k$ by $\phi:(p,v)\in U_\alpha\times\mathbf R^k \mapsto (p,v)\in E_p$. This $\phi$ is surjective, but not injective: if $p$ is in $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$, then both $(p,v)\in U_\alpha\times\mathbf R^k$ and $(p,v)\in U_\beta\times\mathbf R^k$ are sent to $(p,v)\in E_p$. The obvious solution is to define the relation ${\sim}$ by: for $(p,v)\in U_\alpha\times\mathbf R^k$ and $(q,w)\in U_\beta\times\mathbf R^k$, say that $(p,v)\sim(q,w)$ when $p=q$ and $w=\tau_{\alpha\beta}(p)v$. Then $\phi$ gives a bijection $X/{\sim}\to E$, and you can use it to build the bijections $\Phi_\alpha$ in the construction lemma.